# Why don't official English sites translate the OP/ED?

Tags: anime-production, crunchyroll

Many (maybe even all) series on Crunchyroll (perhaps Hulu as well) for example have no subtitles for the opening and ending.

Why is this?

Comment: it's probably going to look ugly having the default subtitle font all over the OP/ED

Comment: The short answer is, I believe, that translation rights for the OP/ED are separate from translation rights for the rest of the show. I'll expand on this later if nobody else does.

Comment: If you'd like to read another person's version of the same answer, [Justin Sevakis was recently asked this question on ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/answerman/2014-05-09) (it's the last one on the page).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was stated by the Support Manager??(or is that just a forum title) of Crunchyroll:

> This involves getting the rights to the songs that are used as opening
>   and endings for each show on the site.
>
> So not only when licensing new simulcasts would we be going after the
>   show but also the opening and ending songs.
>
> A lot of bands are reluctant to let their songs be licensed as this
>   means that the translation presented is -THE- official translation of
>   the song.

Source: http://www.crunchyroll.com/forumtopic-803435/so-crunchyroll-why-not-sub-op-and-ed-songs-as-well

He also backs that up at: http://www.crunchyroll.com/forumtopic-758633/are-cr-subs-lacking-a-bit

So he does seem to be a staff from Crunchyroll.