# Questions about the Korean dubbed Aria series and OPs

Tags: anime-production, aria

**Question 1**

I have noticed that in the Korean dub version of the Aria series, the OP and ED songs are not only subtitled, but are also sung in Korean. How common is it to also dub the OP and ED songs of a not too popular series (cf. *EVA*, *Doraemon*)? And does that require more licensing than [just subtitling the OPs and EDs](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11251/why-dont-official-english-sites-translate-the-op-ed)?

**Question 2**

In the [Korean dubbed OP of *Aria the Animation*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHlnI-Ivy9c), why was the Katakana アリア removed? Does this kind of thing happen in other subbed/dubbed anime OPs or EDs?

[image: Original OP animation in the Chinese sub]

<sup>**Original OP animation in the Chinese sub.**</sup>

[image: Altered art logo in the Korean dub]

<sup>**Altered art logo in the Korean dub.**</sup>

[image: Korean title for Aria the Animation]

**Question 3**

What is it about the Korean dub version of [*Aria the Animation*](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=5504) that requires a director and editing? In contrast, the Italian staff has: a dubbing director, a coordination, a mixing, a post production and a sound engineer. Is any of these roles synonymous to the director or editing in the Korean staff?

[image: Korean staff of Aria the Animation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have sources to cite for all of these, I can maybe come back later and add them if I find them.

1. The reasons songs aren't dubbed are because of the cost of a singer and the additional costs of licensing the rights to re-record the song. There's licensing the rights to simply translate the lyrics but redubbing the vocals would be a completely different recording. Re-recording often happens when the localized dubbed version is intended to be released, so people can buy the localized dub opening theme music (full length versions, etc).
2. As for the katakana missing from the title screen, this is probably entirely an artistic decision. The original 3 katakana fits nicely between the 4 western letters, but in the Korean version, there are only 3 Korean characters which only provides 2 slots for the dots inbetween the characters. They probably decided to make all the dots the same for both the English and Korean for consistency, instead of making the dots in the English word filled in with katakana and have them changed to just dots when the title screen transitioned to Korean. Additionally, they probably didn't want to people to think the katakana was really tiny Korean characters.
3. The director credits for localized versions usually mean the director of the acting. There's a director for the voice acting for a localized dub, just like there's a director for the voice acting in the original Japanese. And just like the recorded acting needs to be edited, mixed, engineered, etc into the final sound tracks in the original Japanese, the same thing needs to happen for a localized dub. I'm guessing that's what the director and editor credits are for.